# Python - Do hashlib's `hash` objects contain any references to the original input value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, security, hash, hashlib

To be very clear, **this is not a question about rainbow tables or reversing hashes from strings**.

This pertains specifically to the data in the memory-space of the instantiated `hash` objects yielded by `hashlib`-- not strings, not the output of `hashlib.sha1(b'4343453').hexdigest()`, but the actual `<sha1 HASH object @ 0x7fe546211720>` objects you get from something like `hashlib.sha1()`.

I am aware that some methods (like `hashlib.sha1().update`) maintain a buffer that operates on incremental data.

- Does this buffer contain the "raw" input or is the algorithm smart enough to handle chunks while enforcing forward secrecy?
- Given the actual `<sha1 HASH object @ 0x7fe546211720>` generated through any of `hashlib`'s functions, is it possible to retrieve any part of the raw input from that?

I'm curious if the integrity of the hash can be compromised in cases where `hash` objects are obtainable/recoverable (i.e. accidentally pickled instead of cast to string).

Thanks!

Comment: Not an answer to your question but you cannot pickle a HASH object.

Comment: @Axe319 Still good to know, thanks!

Comment: "Smart enough"? It is not a matter of smarts, the "raw" data must be buffered until a complete block is available.